# Android - Scoped Directory access - Get access to non existing folder

Tags: android

I have referred [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/scoped-directory-access.html) guide.

I want to create one folder say "XYZ" on the root of sdcard.
So consider the following code: (XYZ folder does not exist on internal or external sd card)

```
    private void aaskForAppyStoreFolderPermission(){
    if(FWCompat.isNougat_24_OrNewer()){
        StorageManager sm = (StorageManager)getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
        File f = new File("/XYZ");
        StorageVolume extStorage = sm.getStorageVolume(f);
        if(extStorage != null) {
            Intent intent = extStorage.createAccessIntent(null);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

But this does not show any popup for accessing XYZ folder.
Now even if I create a folder manually and try again with "/XYZ" or "/storage/emulated/0" or "/storage/459-C045/XYZ" path. It still does not work.

But if I try to get access for whole external memory card : as following then it shows the popup but the message says that do you wish to grant access the complete sd card (which is correct but not what I need. As I want access to only one particular folder (which may or may not exist))
The code to get access to whole memory card:

```
    private void askForAppyStoreFolderPermission(){
    if(FWCompat.isNougat_24_OrNewer()){
        StorageManager sm = (StorageManager)getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
        List<StorageVolume> volumeList = sm.getStorageVolumes();
        if(volumeList != null && volumeList.size() > 0){
            StorageVolume extStorage = volumeList.get(volumeList.size() - 1);
            if(extStorage != null) {
                Intent intent = extStorage.createAccessIntent(null);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageVolume#createAccessIntent(java.lang.String)) it shows what directories you can get access to:

- DIRECTORY_ALARMS
- DIRECTORY_DCIM
- DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS
- DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS
- DIRECTORY_MOVIES
- DIRECTORY_MUSIC
- DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS
- DIRECTORY_PICTURES
- DIRECTORY_PODCASTS
- DIRECTORY_RINGTONES

I wanted to do the same thing you tried to do (read/write to a folder at the root or create if it doesn't exist), unfortunately it's either one of these or the very root of the SD card (with `createAccessIntent(null)`).

From there you can then search through the tree to see if your folder exists and if it doesn't, create it directly at the root by doing something like:

```
Uri u = myintent.getData(); //pass this in onActivityResult(...)!
DocumentFile wholeSD = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(myContext,u);
DocumentFile myFolder = wholeSD.findFile("myfolder");

if(myFolder.exists()) {
    if(myFolder.isDirectory()) {
        doStuff();
    }
} else {
    wholeSD.createDirectory("myFolder");
}
```

You can also try getting the actual path to the SD card (see my answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132764/getting-the-path-to-sd-card/50132809) question) but there's no guarantee that it'll work on every phone, plus you only get reading access - as soon as you try to write something like you would in the normal external storage (non-removable/built in), it'll probably give you a "no access" exception.